Tips for determining molecular point groups
Does anybody have tips on how to easyily determine the point group of a molecule? I am having a hard time even with the simple molecules. For example:

Determine the symmetry of the conformation of ethane from which the substitution of one hydrogen atom produces a molecule with point group Cs, the substitution of two hydrogen atoms produces molecules with point groups C2v, C2 and Cs, and the substitution of three hydrogen atoms produces molecules with point groups C3v, Cs and C1.

Two conformations of ethane are possible -- staggered and eclipsed, right? If I carry out the procedure described in the assignment and check the symmetry of the resulting molecules, I should arrive at the correct solution. As I already mentioned, I am having trouble doing this. Thanks.

Where is the trouble you have got? Have you trouble in understanding the meaning of Cs, C2 and C2v ? Are you unable to draw the ethane molecule ? Please explain.

I don’t understand how to determine the symmetry of a molecule.

There is an explanation at this site https://molecule-viewer.com/  but mainly you can choose molecules and add symmetry elements and test yourself

If you are able to draw the molecule in three dimensions, you should be able to see if the molecule has one or several symmetry planes, and one or several symmetry axis.
